# In Rails, how do I prevent my search function from automatically running a blank search on page load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that has a search function. The search function displays  an alert message it a user doesn't enter anything into the search field. The problem is that this message displays when the page loads - before submit has been clicked. How do I prevent this?

Here is my controller code:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if params[:q].blank?
      @message = 'Please enter an address in the field!'
      return
    end

    token = Rails.application.credentials.locationiq_key
    search = LocationiqApi.new(token).find_place(params[:q])

    # Hash#dig will return nil if ANY part of the lookup fails
    latitude = search.dig('searchresults', 'place', 'lat')
    longitude = search.dig('searchresults', 'place', 'lon')

    if latitude.nil? || longitude.nil?
      # Output an error message if lat or lon is nil
      @coordinates = "We couldn't find a place by this name. Please enter a valid place name."
    else
      @coordinates = "Coordinates: " + "#{latitude}, #{longitude}"
    end
  end
end
```

and my view:

```
<main>
  <h1>Location Search</h1>
  <!-- devise flash messages -->
  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <!-- Button to search coordinates -->
  <%= form_tag(locations_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("geocode") %>
    <%= @message %>
  <% end %><br>

  <%= @coordinates %>
</main>
```

Comment: Why do you want to show an error message when the user doesn't enter a query? Why not simple show all results?

Comment: The coordinates for all places in the world? That would be quite a lot of results to show ;)

Comment: With pagination of course.

Answer (score 0):

Inside location search form add,

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'location_search', true %>
```

In controller check as,

```
if  params[:location_search] && params[:q].blank?
   @message = 'Please enter an address in the field!'
   return
end
```

Comment: The `== true` should be able to be removed without any change in the result

Comment: @2017kamb This still has the same result: the message is still being shown on page reload...

Comment: @2017kamb Sorry, I don't understand what you mean? When page loads I now get the message "We couldn't find a place by this name. Please enter a valid place name".

Comment: How you are landing on index page of location controller without any search?

Comment: add required: true in text_field_tag

Comment: @2017kamb localhost:3000/locations

Comment: what is the expectation on first time hit of, localhost:3000/locations  ?

Comment: see actually what happens, when we load index page, we should show all the locations and if user search for specific location we can show accordingly. I am not getting what you actually want?

Comment: @2017kamb when index is loaded i just want a search field and submit button. no results should be displyed and no messages should be displayed

Comment: make a search action then for code seperation and keep index aside.

Comment: @2017kamb Okay, I've done that now. But still getting the same result...

Comment: update the question with your new implementation, then people will check and reply